# Merge old and new config txt file

Tags: bash

How can I update my config file with lines that are not present in old version?

Example:

config.cfg:

```
parameterA=0
parameterB=1
parameterC=0
```

config.cfg.sample:

```
parameterA=0
parameterB=0
parameterC=0
parameterD=0
```

What I want to do is to execute command that will update config.cfg file, using config.cfg.sample file and get as result this:

```
parameterA=0
parameterB=1
parameterC=0
parameterD=0
```

New lines will not always be at the end. Existing lines must not be changed.

For example:

```
update_config.sh config.cfg config.cfg.sample
```

Thank you!

Comment: if you want to append the contents of config.cfg with config.cfg.sample you can simply use command 



`cat config.cfg.sample >> config.cfg`

Comment: Hello, thx, but that would not create requested result. It would duplicate lot of lines but must not duplicate any.

Comment: in that case this way might not be the best but works
` cat config.cfg.sample >> config.cfg | uniq > config.cfg`

Comment: Hello, thanks, still not good, it changed parameterB setting to 0. Must not change existing settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any loop for this join.
There is a tool for this purpose, called join. 
This command will bring you the results you need.

```
join -a1 -a2 -t= b.txt bb.txt |cut -d= -f1-2
```

If you remove the cut at the end you will be able to see the "comparison" between of the two files.

Test:

```
$ cat b.txt
parameterA=0
parameterB=1
parameterC=0

$ cat bb.txt
parameterA=0
parameterB=0
parameterC=0
parameterD=0

$ join -a1 -a2 -t= b.txt bb.txt |cut -d= -f1-2
parameterA=0
parameterB=1
parameterC=0
parameterD=0
```

Comment: Seems that this is best answer. Simplest and works exactly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the work. "config.cfg" is the original file, while "config.new" is the file to get new keywords from.

```
#!/bin/sh

exec 0<config.new
while read line; do
  parname=$(echo "$line" |cut -d= -f1)
  # echo "  (debug) new parname=$parname"
  grep "^$parname" config.cfg || echo $line >> config.cfg
done
```

The rationale is: read config.new line by line; extract the parameter name (via cut), determine if this parameter name is contained in the original file and, if not, append it to the file.

New parameters will always be appended to the original file, though. Passing the final file through sort could perhaps help, if this is wanted.

An aside note: perhaps the `cut` command could even be avoided because the shell can do that kind of field extraction. I chose to keep things simple.

Comment: Hello, this one seems simpler so I believe will work from this. It also retains everything that config.cfg contained (like for example added comments) but config.new does not, which I prefer for my solution. Thanks.